# How to FTP directly to a sub-directory?

Tags: debian, command-line, wget, pure-ftpd

An FTP site allows anonymous access to a particular directory, and I would like to download a file from it.

PureFTP and wget keep trying to login to the server's root directory, even when I give wget the fully qualified file, and the login fails accordingly.

**How do I FTP directly to this subdirectory/file?**

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `lftp`, setting first

```
ftp:home /particulardirectory
```

in LFTP's config file `~/.lftprc`.

From the manpage:

```
ftp:home (string)
              Initial directory. Default is empty string which means auto. Set this to  `/'  if  you
              don't  like  the  look  of  %2F  in  FTP URLs. The closure for this setting has format
              user@host.
```

Comment: Thanks dr01, but I still get 530 login failed.